# Having hangup with IF AND OR functions. Need one last tweak

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2007

Disclaimer: I have never written code in Excel before. I have been building something for work during few days.  I have a formula that WORKS!  But there is one adjustment that I need to make, that I cannot make happen. Here is what I have. (Again, if its messy, I have no idea, but its currently working).

```
=IF(AND(D5="Yes LSC, PA's passed")*F5>G5-20,"AT0 Cannot be in same month as W/D",IF(AND(D5="Yes LSC, PA's not passed")*F5>G5-20,"AT0 Cannot be in same month as W/D",IF(AND(E5="Yes, systematic W/D")*F5>G5-20,"AT0 Cannot be in same month as a systematic W/D","")))
```

Background:  I need an excel spreadsheet that we give to new employees as a "cheatsheet" It gives them prompts (I.E "Yes, LSC passed, or Yes, W/D"). They select the prompts and pass to a supervisor for processing.

Goal: I'm trying to write a formula that does not allow simple errors. For my purposes, I know Cell G5 must be AT LEAST 20 greater than F5. So I want an error message to appear every time they try to enter a value that breaks that rule. (Saves management time) And all of that WORKS!

Problem: If G5 is BLANK...It still gives me the message that I've told it to. However, IF G5 is BLANK, I don't need any of the formula to run.  I have been trying to build this exception into my amateur formula but I cant get it.

I can understand whats happening.... Excel recognizes that if G5 is blank...then F5>G5-20  is TRUE -- And it gives me text that I want!!  But I need an exception... I need it say understand that if G5 is BLANK, then I don't care about F5>G5-20.  It can ignore the ENTIRE formula.

Any suggestions? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Well... I think I found a solution! In hindsight, its incredibly intuitive, and a little embarrassing. I just added     IF(G5="","", ... then the rest of my formula.
But if anyone still reads this and has words of wisdom, I'll be happy to hear it. This is my first experience.

Answer (score 1):

How would this be?

```
=IF(ISBLANK(G5),"-", //insert your forumla here// )
```

Answer (score 0):

*an error message to appear every time they try to enter a value that breaks that rule* is often handled with Data Validation rather than an IF function. I take it F5 will be completed before G5. Select G5, DATA > Data Tools - Data Validation, Data Validation..., Settings, Allow: Custom, Formula:

```
=G5>=F5+20
```

With other settings in their default state this should allow G5 to be blank (or to be populated and then blanked) but give a warning sound and message "The value you entered is not valid." at any attempt to key in an non-compliant value. The warning message may be customised and there is also an option to show an input message where entry of an invalid value is attempted, which might be used to explain the requirement. Alternatively the value might be accepted but later marked as being non-compliant.

It is though rather easy to bypass the validation - just copying from elsewhere and pasting into G5 could do so. Though copying from elsewhere and pasting into the cell with the IF formula would bypass that control too.

Data Validation might also substitute for some of the rest of your IF formula.